# How do I find the full definition of a user-defined constraint in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

All I know about the constraint is it's name, but I want to see the columns it is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
select OWNER, CONSTRAINT_NAME, CONSTRAINT_TYPE, TABLE_NAME, SEARCH_CONDITION from  
ALL_CONSTRAINTS where CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'Constraint_name';
```

or

```
DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('CONSTRAINT', 'constraint_name')
```